# Download only last published package files in specific version

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to download only last published package files in specific version? Currently im storing recent 25 snapshots of artifact, but I do want to download with DownloadPackage task only the last one that was published.

So I do have:

- blablabla-0.0.3-20210310.134011-61.jar
- blablabla-0.0.3-20210310.132011-60.jar
- blablabla-0.0.3-20210309.131111-59.jar
- ...

And i want download only blablabla-0.0.3-20210310.134011-61.jar

We are talking about this task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-package?view=azure-devops

Comment: Is my reply helpful?

Comment: It didn't help me in any way

Comment: You may submit a user voice at website below: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `latest` in this case if you want to download the latest version of the package at runtime.

Something like the following should do the trick for you:

```
- task: DownloadPackage@1
  inputs:
    packageType: 'maven'
    feed: <feedID>
    view: <VIEW>
    definition: <PACKAGE>
    version: 'latest'
    downloadPath: <PATH_TO_DOWNLOAD>
```

Comment: Sorry, but you did not understood me well. I don't want everytime the latest VERSION of package but i want the last published file in version, not all the snapshots that were created in f.e. latest version

Comment: those: 
blablabla-0.0.3-20210310.134011-61.jar
blablabla-0.0.3-20210310.132011-60.jar
blablabla-0.0.3-20210309.131111-59.jar
are in package specific version (0.0.3), i want only one with "61" ending

Comment: Ah I see, well as you download this to the agent, you can just add aditional step to clean up a bit  in the target folder (i.e. bash task to filter out and remove jars that you do not need).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify files to be downloaded in `files` argument:

```
- task: DownloadPackage@1
  inputs:
    packageType: 'maven'
    feed: # <feedId> for organization-scoped feeds, <projectId>/<feedId> for project-scoped feeds.
    definition: # '$(packageName)'
    version: # '1.0.0'
    files: 'blablabla-0.0.3-20210310.134011-61.jar'
    downloadPath: # '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

Comment: Okey, once again back to my primary question: Can i extract only the last one that was published, not a specific file like you have provided :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such option by default. :(

Comment: That is very weird, I thought its normal approach :/

Comment: You may submit a user voice at website below: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion.